# Change color of scrollbar of CListCtrl

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a class derived from CListCtrl, named CListCtrlExt, which I need to change the color of scrollbars ... how can I achieve that ?
I made an trial, like that:

```
HBRUSH CListCtrlExt::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
HBRUSH hbr = CListCtrl::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

// TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

if(CTLCOLOR_SCROLLBAR == nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));   
    HBRUSH b = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(233,233,220));   
    return b;   
}

// TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired
return hbr;
}
```

nor even pass by here ... another trial:

```
HBRUSH CTestDlg2Dlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

// TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

if(pWnd == GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1) && CTLCOLOR_SCROLLBAR == nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HBRUSH b = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    return b;   
}

// TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired
return hbr;
}
```

not working either ... 
I also have a CScrollbarEx (from [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/developing-a-custom-windows-scrollbar-in/184416659)), but I don't know how to attach it on my CListCtrlExt ... can you help me, please ?

Comment: That class you provided in the link seems pretty complete and provides what you want.  It's written for an older version of MFC but you should be able to adapt it.  Have you tried deriving your class from the one provided in the zip from that link?

Comment: Kindly thank you for your interest. Infact, the scrollbar inside of zipped project is working well, the problem is that I don't know how to attach it on my CListCtrlExt ... this is the issue ... :)

Comment: Have you unzipped the contents of the link and tried the test program that's included?  You should be able to determine from the test program, and the accompanying source code, how it all fits together.  HINT:  the scroll bar appears to be defined as a CStatic control in the resource file of the test program.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but I am not figure out how to use this CScrollBarEx object into CListCtrl derived object ... :(

Comment: Be careful, it might be possible the CListCtrl drawing is being handled by the theme visual manager (CMFCVisualManager )

Comment: I don't use CMFCVisualManager ... but to be honest, I didn't succeded yet ... I didn't realize that is such a hard thing to change the color of the scrollbar of an control ...